# Define multiple tags and remove suites in behat.yml

Tags: selenium, yaml, bdd, behat, gherkin

I want to define multiple tags in behat.yml which correspond to suite names.
There are 4 suites inside the features folder and each of them have multiple .feature files.

Ex: admin, themes

Tags to be defined: @admin, @themes.

Previously the behat.yml file contained suites for admin and themes. Now I want to define 3 different profiles (server1, server2 and server3) corresponding to different testing environments and use tags instead of suites to run the feature files containing those tags. I have added the tags @admin and @themes in every feature file of themes and admin folder.

How should I implement this specific case in my config file? 
Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have different profiles and themes as per the [docs](http://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration.html)

So one possible way to do it, would be to group the suites for each profile.

```
server1:
  suites:
    default:
        contexts:
            - FeatureContext
        filters:
            tags: "@admin"
server2:
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext        
            filters:
                tags: "@admin"

server3:
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext        
            filters:
                tags: "@admin,@themes"
```